# Add custom autocomplete to react-ace EUI Kibana

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kibana, ace-editor

I'm trying to add custom autocomplete for the editor inside the Kibana EUI framework.

Basically, I have this code:

```
<EuiCodeEditor
                    mode="yaml"
                    theme="github"
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    className="ace-tm"
                    value={configurationText}
                    onChange={(e) => onChangeEventText(e)}
                    setOptions={{
                        fontSize: '14px',
                        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
                        enableSnippets: true,
                        enableLiveAutocompletion: true
                    }}
                    onBlur={() => {
                        console.log('blur');
                    }} // eslint-disable-line no-console
                    aria-label="Code Editor"
                    onLoad = {editor => {   
                        console.log("EDITOR");
                        console.log(editor);
                        console.log(editor.completers);
                      //  editor.completers = [staticWordCompleter];
                      /*  var mode = editor.getMode();   
                        mode.getCompletions =  (state, session, pos, prefix) => {
                            return [];
                        } ; 
                        editor.setMode(mode);
                        editor.completers = [staticWordCompleter];*/
                    }}
                />
```

And as you can see inside the onLoad I'm getting the editor pointer in order to add the custom autocomplete, but is not working. The ace editor documentation is not so good for the react-ace inside the Eui framework, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT1**
Resolved as you can read inside the answer, now I'm facing another problem: the autocomplete suggest either custom and keyword inside the document. I need only my custom suggestion. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved, I added this import:

```
import 'brace/ext/language_tools';
```

And wrote my onLoad as follow:

```
onLoad={editor => {

                        var mode = editor.getSession().getMode();

                        mode.getCompletions = (state, session, pos, prefix, callback) => {
                            var completions = [];
                            
                            ["example1", "example2"].forEach(function (w) {

                                completions.push({
                                    value: w,
                                    meta: "my completion",
                                    snippet: `@{${w || ""}}`,
                                    caption: w || ""

                                });
                            });

                            return completions;
                          
                        }

                        editor.getSession().setMode(mode);

                        console.log("EDITOR");
                        console.log(editor.getSession().getMode().getCompletions());

                    }}
```

Now I'm facing another problem and I'm updating the question

Comment: try using `editor.completers = [{getCompletions: function() {...}]` instead